# Windowed Store not getting filled (Spring Cloud Stream Kafka)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to create a windowed store from a bunch of data points, but it looks like that stream topology branch isn't evaluated for some reason.

I use the same stream to fill a `KTable` materialized into a store, and that works fine.

I'm using Spring Cloud Streams with the following configuration:

```
spring:
  application.name: stream-test

  kafka.bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092

  cloud.stream:
    # assign group and topic name to binding
    bindings:
      windowedStream:
        destination: myTopic
        group: stream-test-window
    kafka:
      # configure kafka binder
      binder:
        brokers: ${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}
        configuration.auto.offset.reset: latest
      # kafka-streams specific binding configuration
      streams.bindings.windowedStream.consumer:
        keySerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
        valueSerde: kstreamstest.StreamSerdes$DataItemSerde
```

The `DataItemSerde` is just an extended JSON-Serde (also works for the `KTable`).

```
@Data class DataItem {
    String value;
}

public class StreamSerdes {
    public static final Serde<DataItem> DATA_ITEM_SERDE = new DataItemSerde();
    public static class DataItemSerde extends JsonSerde<DataItem> {}
}
```

With the Binding

```
interface WindowedTableBinding {
    String WINDOW_STREAM = "windowedStream";

    @Input(WINDOW_STREAM)
    KStream<String, DataItem> stream();
}
```

I create a stream listener like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableBinding(WindowedTableBinding.class)
class StreamToWindowed {
    String storeName = "wvs";

    @Bean
    String windowedStoreName() {
        return storeName;
    }

    @StreamListener(WindowedTableBinding.WINDOW_STREAM)
    public void windowStream(@Input(WindowedTableBinding.WINDOW_STREAM) KStream<String, DataItem> stream) {
        stream.peek((k, v)  -> System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", k, v))
                .groupByKey()
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(5_000))
                .reduce((d1, d2) -> d2,
                    Materialized
                        .<String, DataItem, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("wvs")
                        .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                        .withValueSerde(StreamSerdes.DATA_ITEM_SERDE));
    }
}
```

However, when I then query the store

```
Set<String> getWindowedKeys() {
    ReadOnlyWindowStore<String, DataItem> queryableStore = queryService
            .getQueryableStore(windowedStoreName, QueryableStoreTypes.windowStore());
    Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
    if (queryableStore != null) { // store is not null though
        try (KeyValueIterator<Windowed<String>, DataItem> values = queryableStore.all()) {
            values.forEachRemaining(kvs -> result.add(kvs.key.key()));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

that set is always empty (after I send in data of course). The `System.out.print` statements are also not triggered, so I guess the branch is not evaluated at all.

Again, I establish a `KTable` for the same values in parallel, and that gets filled fine. I can remove it and the windowed version still doesn't work.

I did see [this example](https://github.com/schacko-samples/kafka-streams-multiprocessor/blob/master/src/main/java/kafka/streams/multiprocessor/kafkastreamsmultiprocessor/KafkaStreamsMultiprocessorApplication.java) but the only difference I see is that it writes the data back to an output stream, which I don't want to do. Also, it doesn't help if I add it.

I also tried

```
@KafkaStreamsStateStore(name="wvs", type= KafkaStreamsStateStoreProperties.StoreType.WINDOW, lengthMs=5_000)
public void windowStream(@Input(WindowedTableBinding.WINDOW_STREAM) KStream<String, DataItem> stream) {}
```

but that doesn't make a difference.

What do I have to do to fill that windowed data store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual for me with Spring, this turns out to have been a configuration issue.

I needed to give separate `application-id`s for the two bindings:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings:
    tableStream.consumer:
        application-id: table-generator
    windowedStream.consumer:
        application-id: windows-generator
```

Comment: Glad it worked out. You might want to accept your own answer as anyone else running into the same issue might benefit in the future.